# Add comma-separated value of grouped rows to existing query

Tags: sql, csv, group-by, oracle10g

I've got a view for reports, that looks something like this:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.value1,
  a.value2,
  b.value1,
  /* (+50 more such columns)*/
FROM a
JOIN b ON (b.id = a.b_id)
JOIN c ON (c.id = b.c_id)
LEFT JOIN d ON (d.id = b.d_id)
LEFT JOIN e ON (e.id = d.e_id)
/* (+10 more inner/left joins) */
```

It joins quite a few tables and returns lots of columns, but indexes are in place and performance is fine.

Now I want to add another column to the result, showing

- comma-separated values
- ordered by value
- from table y
- outer joined via intersection table x
- if `a.value3 IS NULL`, else take `a.value3`

To comma-separate the grouped values I use [Tom Kyte's stragg](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402), could use [`COLLECT`](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402#18313422264397) later.

Pseudo-code for the SELECT would look like that:

```
SELECT xx.id, COALESCE( a.value3, stragg( xx.val ) ) value3
FROM (
  SELECT x.id, y.val
  FROM x
  WHERE x.a_id = a.id
  JOIN y ON ( y.id = x.y_id )
  ORDER BY y.val ASC
) xx
GROUP BY xx.id
```

What is the best way to do it? Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 11.2.x has a new function LISTAGG.  Maybe this new function is arriving too late for you?

example (From TK in Ora Mag):

```
SQL> select deptno,
  2         listagg( ename, '; ' )
  3         within group
  4         (order by ename) enames
  5     from emp
  6    group by deptno
  7    order by deptno;

  DEPTNO   ENAMES
---------  --------------------
  10       CLARK; KING; MILLER
  20       ADAMS; FORD; JONES;
           SCOTT; SMITH

  30       ALLEN; BLAKE;
           JAMES; MARTIN;
           TURNER; WARD
```

Comment: I'm using 10g (see tags of my question), so this does not help me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

u can just concatenate all the columns, using ||','||.
for ur query,

a.id||','||
  a.value1||','||
  a.value2||','||
  b.value1||','||
  /* (+50 more such columns)*/
FROM a
JOIN b ON (b.id = a.b_id)
JOIN c ON (c.id = b.c_id)
LEFT JOIN d ON (d.id = b.d_id)
LEFT JOIN e ON (e.id = d.e_id);
this wil give u commas in the .csv format.
or u can use any tool like dbvisualizer or execute qyery.